# Why does my rear LCD display change its orientation upside down automatically and continuously?

Tags: troubleshooting, nikon-d5100, rear-lcd

Recently, after 4 years of trouble free service, my Nikon D5100 LCD screen has developed a snag. Info display changes its orientation upside down continuously as a flicker. However in playback mode, pictures are shown normally. I even upgraded the firmware but the problem persists. I tried changing between Classic & Graphical display but no improvement is seen.

What's going on, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This is most likely a faulty orientation sensor. This is the sensor that supplies orientation information for the camera to record and write inside each photo's metadata. It's expected that playback mode is not affected as it just follows the same information for each photo and the "Rotate Tall" setting (which dictates whether portrait-oriented photos should be rotated for playback).

Referring to the [manual](http://download.nikonimglib.com/archive2/bFpVn006cKZa029I4QC02Vipsb29/D5100RM_EU(En)02.pdf), it seems that it's not possible to disable the Info display auto-rotation.

It would be a good idea to take the camera to a Nikon service centre - they might be able to replace the  faulty module for a small fee.